# Tradingview strategy with 3commas bot

Tags: pine-script

Hello I'm trying so set this up but am getting no signal to the bot. I have no Idea what I'm doing so any help would be awesome. I have tried the settings from 3Commas but still not working.

// Make sure we are within the bar range, Set up entries and exit conditions
if ((ebar==0 or tdays<=ebar) and tradeType!="NONE")
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=longCond==true and tradeType!="SHORT", comment==  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 66xxx18,  "email_token": "9c93c7ce-337e-4ac3-93a7-xxxxx8c8",  "delay_seconds": 1}  ' //start long deal)
strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when=shortCond==true and tradeType!="LONG"
strategy.close("long", when = shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG", comment= comment==  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 66xxxx8,  "email_token": "9c93c7ce-337xxxxc8",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "action": "close_at_market_price"}  ' // close long deal market ))
strategy.close("short", when = longCond==true and tradeType=="SHORT")
strategy.exit("XL", from_entry = "long", profit = TP, loss = SL)
strategy.exit("XS", from_entry = "short", profit = TP, loss = SL)

// === /STRATEGY ===
Long        =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 661XX18,  "email_token": "9c93c51b0c58c8",  "delay_seconds": 1}  ' //start long deal

ExitLong    =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 66xxxx18,  "email_token": "9c93c0c58c8",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "action": "close_at_market_price"}  ' // close long deal market

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=longCond==true and tradeType!= "SHORT", comment="Long", alert_message= Long)

strategy.close("long", when=shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG", comment="Close", alert_message= ExitLong)

Comment: Please format your question and code. Please use code sample `{}` button to wrap your code.

Comment: Is this your whole code? Also please tell us how you setup your bot on 3commas side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.